# How does event-driven programming background code look like?

Tags: events

We always use event driver programming to create desktop applications with user interfaces. In such frameworks we only associate functions to events. But we can never see how does it work in the background. How does the real application generated by the framework look like. What does the main function contain. I imagine something like the following :

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
       wait_for_an_event();
       handle_the_recived_event();        
    }

}
```

If you have any clarifications, details about this, I would be so greatuful

Comment: Event models can be created in all sorts of ways.  What programming language are you specifically using?  They rarely involve loops.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about using .NET

Events on .Net are a way to signal notifications to clients of a class.  They are also built in and are fairly easy to implement.

You can read about them here: [Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I know them and i work with them all the time but my question is something else read again the question please

Comment: I guess I don't understand at all what you are asking then